# pushing UIViewController without Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, xcode4.5

I was using that  method for pushing another UIViewController in if condition  :

```
initViewController *MW = [initViewController alloc];
MW = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"init"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:MW animated:YES];
```

Now i've changed my architecture and i just removed my Navigation controller. That's why , these steps will not help me any longer due to no NavigationController exist. Now how can i push another ViewController without pressing button -(IBAction) . I just wanted to use it in Storyboard.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI : without UINavigationController You can't push to another Controller . You can produce a Controller using

> **PresentViewController**

```
 [self presentViewController:objPortrit animated:YES completion:^{    }];
```

For Ex:

```
 initViewController *MW = [initViewController alloc];
   MW = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"init"];
    [self presentViewController:MW animated:YES completion:^{

            }];
```

**EDIT**:

```
For your comment :
```

after producing the ViewController with PresentViewController, You need to dismiss it to produce another ViewController .

You can get over from this , something like this in their respective ViewController Use his method. :

```
 -(void)viewDidDisappear {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that quick answer. It works and handled all my problems :D

Comment: One problem has just shown :) - Warning: Attempt to present <initViewController: 0x1cdda700> on <Login: 0x1cdb2960> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!